# Django UpdateView: Object to update has no values

Tags: python, django, updates, django-generic-views

I'd like to update an object with generic view updateview. The problem arises when I edit an object. Instead of reaching a prefilled form, I reach a blank form.
My template for this:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Update" />
    <a  href="{% url 'display_targetbehavior' %}" class="btn btn-default">Take me back</a>
    </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

In my views.py

```
class HabitUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Habit
    form_class = HabitForm
    #fields = ('title', 'trigger', 'existingroutine', 'targetbehavior', 'image')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('display_habits')
    template_name = 'habits/update_habit.html'
```

my model:

```
class Habit(models.Model):
    AFTER = 'After I'
    WHEN = 'When I'
    WHENEVER = 'Whenever I'
    BEFORE = 'Before I'
    MEANWHILE = 'Meanwhile I'

    TRIGGER_CHOICES = (
      (AFTER, 'After I'),
      (WHEN, 'When I'),
      (WHENEVER, 'Whenever I'),
      (BEFORE, 'Before I'),
      (MEANWHILE, 'Meanwhile I'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    trigger = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TRIGGER_CHOICES, default=AFTER)
    existingroutine = models.ForeignKey(
      'Existingroutine',
      on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
      blank=True,
      null = True,
    )
    targetbehavior = models.ForeignKey(
      'Targetbehavior',
      on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
      blank=True,
      null = True,
    )

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='habit_image', blank=True)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         habitpresentation = self.title# + '\n ' + self.trigger + '\n ' + str(self.existingroutine) + '\n ' + str(self.targetbehavior)
    return habitpresentation

    def image_url(self):
        #print(self.image.url)
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url
        else:
            return None;
```

..and in my forms.py

```
class HabitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Habit
        fields = ( 'title', 'trigger', 'existingroutine', 'targetbehavior', 'image')


    def save(self, commit=True):
        habit = super(HabitForm, self).save(commit=False)
        habit.title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        habit.trigger = self.cleaned_data['trigger']
        habit.existingroutine = self.cleaned_data['existingroutine']
        habit.targetbehavior = self.cleaned_data['targetbehavior']
        habit.image = self.cleaned_data['image']

        if commit:
            habit.save()
```

**EDIT**
urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
```

from habits import views as habits_views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', habits_views.display_habits, name='display_habits'),
    url(r'^habit/details/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.display_habit_details, name='display_habit_details'),
    url(r'^habit/details/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/delete/$', habits_views.delete_habit, name='delete_habit'),
    #url(r'^habit/details/update/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.update_habit, name='update_habit'),
    url(r'^habit/details/update/(?P<pk>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.HabitUpdate.as_view(), name='update_habit'),
    url(r'^habit/create-habit/$', habits_views.create_habit, name='create_habit'),
    url(r'^existingroutines/$', habits_views.display_existing_routines, name='display_existing_routines'),
    url(r'^existingroutines/create/$', habits_views.create_existing_routine, name='create_existing_routine'),
    url(r'^existingroutines/select/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.select_existing_routine, name='select_existing_routine'),
    url(r'^existingroutines/update/(?P<pk>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.ExistingroutineUpdate.as_view(), name='update_existing_routine'),
    url(r'^existingroutines/delete/(?P<pk>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.ExistingroutineDelete.as_view(), name='delete_existing_routine'),
    url(r'^targetbehavior/$', habits_views.display_targetbehavior, name='display_targetbehavior'),
    url(r'^targetbehavior/create/$', habits_views.create_targetbehavior, name='create_targetbehavior'),
    url(r'^targetbehavior/select/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.select_targetbehavior, name='select_targetbehavior'),
    url(r'^targetbehavior/update/(?P<pk>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.TargetbehaviorUpdate.as_view(), name='update_targetbehavior'),
    url(r'^targetbehavior/delete/(?P<pk>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.TargetbehaviorDelete.as_view(), name='delete_targetbehavior'),
]
```

With this url I'm going to update the habit:

```
url(r'^habit/details/update/(?P<pk>\w{0,50})/$', habits_views.HabitUpdate.as_view(), name='update_habit'),
```

**EDIT**
get_object delivers object. 
[image]

Any suggests?

Comment: Your `save` method is pointless, but that is not the cause of your problem. Can you post your urls, and show which URL you are going to to display the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `UpdateView` is not returning the right object for your template. Have you tried this:

```
class HabitUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Habit
    form_class = HabitForm
    template_name = 'habits/update_habit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('display_habits')

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(HabitUpdate, self).get_initial()
        print('initial data', initial)

        # retrieve current object
        habit_object = self.get_object()

        initial['field1'] = habit_object.field1
        initial['field2'] = habit_object.field2
        ....
        ....
        return initial


    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        habit = get_object_or_404(Habit, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

        return habit
```

And you only need this in your `forms.py` file:

```
class HabitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Habit
        fields = ( 'title', 'trigger', 'existingroutine', 'targetbehavior', 'image')
```

Comment: Great.Glad that it helps you out.

Comment: Okay, sry I was a bit overhasty. It seems that pretty rare the form is filled with the right values. And most of the case values are not populated and the form fields are blank. Rare means 2 times were given the right values of perceived 100 trys/refreshs. 
get_object gets the right object/habit. So whats wrong with them?

Comment: Can you try override ```get_initial``` method and load the initial object like above? For each object, the get_initial will be called and there should be data for that object.

Comment: Are you sure there is data in the database for that particular object? Have you checked in `shell` ?

Comment: My url http://localhost:8000/overview/habit/details/update/3/ implicit that pk=self.kwargs['pk'] --> pk = 3 (already tested).
Edit question above contains screenshot of db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145453/discussion-between-sijan-bhandari-and-texas).