# Django UpdateView - no object due to POST call

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have two UpdateViews, one works and the other doesn't...  **Please see Update IV**

The working model is:

**views.py**

```
class JuryUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Jury
    fields = [
        'jury_name',
        ]
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(Jury, jury_id=self.kwargs['jr'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.court_year = self.kwargs['yr']
        form.instance.jury_id = self.kwargs['jr']
        return super(JuryUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

**templates/jury_update_form.html** (in relevant part)

```
<div class="container">
    <h5>Update {{for.instance.jury_name}}</h5>
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This setup will render an updateview with the object labels and existing field data from the object.  This next setup doesn't work...

**views.py**

```
class CustomerUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Customer
    fields = [
        'customer',
        ]
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(Customer, customer_id=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.customer_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super(CustomerUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

**templates/customer_update_form.html** (in relevant part)

```
<div class="container">
    <h5>Update {{form.instance.customer}}</h5>
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The second updateview does provide an update form but it doesn't populate with the calling object's data.  It would seem that the object is there since the `{{form.instance.customer}}` contains the correct `customer` data for the call (no different than the JuryUpdate view).

I've tried to explicitly call `get_initial` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259552/django-updateview-object-to-update-has-no-values)) and print, but the result is `{}`.  I've also tried variation of the `form_valid` call but as presented above, I believe I'm getting the correct object.  There are several examples (such as [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/lRXVQxmS30s)) that use `get_initial` to pre-populate with existing information - but that doesn't work in this instance and it isn't needed in my `JuryUpdate` view.

Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE I***

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer"
        verbose_name_plural = "Customers"

    customer_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)

    customer = models.CharField(
        max_length=40)

    # table fields

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'customer-detail-view', 
            kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer

class Jury(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Jury"
        verbose_name_plural = "Juries"

    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    court_year = models.ForeignKey(
        CourtYear,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    jury_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)

    jury_name  = models.CharField(
        max_length=20)

    # other table fields

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'jury-list-view', 
            kwargs={'pk':self.customer_id, 'yr':self.court_year_id})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.jury_name
```

**urls.py**

```
path('add_customer/', views.CustomerCreate.as_view(), name='customer-add'),
path('<int:pk>/', views.CustomerDetailView.as_view(), name='customer-detail-view'),
path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.CustomerDelete.as_view(), name='customer-delete'),   
path('<int:pk>/update/', views.CustomerUpdate.as_view(), name='customer-update'),

path('<int:pk>/<int:yr>/', views.JuryListView.as_view(), name='jury-list-view'),
path('<int:pk>/<int:yr>/add_jury/', views.JuryCreate.as_view(), name='jury-add'),
path('<int:pk>/<int:yr>/<int:jr>/updatejury', views.JuryUpdate.as_view(), name='jury-update'),
path('<int:pk>/<int:yr>/<int:jr>/deletejury', views.JuryDelete.as_view(), name='jury-delete'),
```

***UPDATE II***

I've added a `get_initial()` method to my `CustomerUpdate(UpdateView)` as follows:

```
def get_initial(self):

    initial = super(CustomerUpdate, self).get_initial()
    print('initial data', initial)

    customer_object = self.get_object()

    initial['customer'] = customer_object.customer
    # other fields omitted...

    print('initial data updated', initial)

    return initial
```

The `initial data` print returns `{}`.  The `initial data updated` print returns `{'customer': 'John Doe'}` (plus the "other fields").  So it seems that the right information is getting pulled and delivered - It must be in the `html`?

***Update III***

I've taken the `CustomerUpdate(UpdateView)` down to the very basic class model:

```
class CustomerUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Customer
    fields = [
        'customer',
        ]
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

The template is already the basic format ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)) - the rendered webpage still doesn't have object data for updating...

**Update IV**

*I think I've figured out the problem - but don't know how to fix...*

When I use the `JuryUpdate` call the console shows:

```
[02/Jun/2018 16:19:19] "GET /myapp/1/3/9/updatejury/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=1kHK4xgqdbBfXsv6mtz0WKgKpewFwLVtpUX5Z51qnLsGaMDVmpdVHKslXAXPhvY8 HTTP/1.1" 200 3687
```

When I use the `CustomerUpdate` call the console shows:

```
[02/Jun/2018 16:18:57] "POST /myapp/5/update/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3354
```

So my updateview on the Jury update is a `GET` call while my udpateview on Customer is a`POST` call.  In looking through the docs, I can see that the `GET` call with show the data while the `POST` call is (I think) assuming a black data set.  I can't figure out why I'm getting a different result - where would this be set/changed?

Comment: Before looking further — the "Customer" field in `CustomerUpdate` should probably be lower-case? Impossible to be certain without looking at your models, but your narrative suggests that's the wrong capitalisation. (This may or may not be the cause of your actual problem, though.)

Comment: @JamesAylett - my typo on SO - fixed.

Comment: Does your `Customer` really have a `customer` field? That seems…unexpected. It highlights that this isn't a complete enough view to see what's going on — your urlconf and models may be needed for someone to help.

Comment: Use Python 3 so you don't need to rewrite this in a year and a half when Python 2 looses all support.

Comment: @kagronick - this is running in 3.6.5 (?)

Comment: @Bill super() doesn't need arguments on Python 3. Most people don't put it because it breaks the DRY rule and makes it harder to refactor class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days - I traced the issue - it had nothing to do with the view, model, url or the update template.  The offending code was actually attached to the update button.  Very specifically the page that had the button for "Update" used the following `<form>` code:

```
<form action="{% url 'customer-update' pk=customer.client_id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-xs">U</button>
</form>
```

In the form call the method used was `"POST"` - and although I don't exactly understand the intracacies, the result is a blank UpdateView.  The following code in the calling page fixed the problem.

```
<form action="{% url 'customer-update' pk=customer.client_id %}" style="display: inline;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-custom-xs">U</button>
</form>
```